# How do you specify a test folder/path with Playwright?

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, playwright

I want to be able to specify a folder where my tests live so that Playwright doesn't try to run tests from all folders. Is there a way to tell Playwright to only run tests from a specific folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [testDir](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-test-dir) config option. For example:

```
// playwright.config.ts
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testDir: './tests/playwright',
};

export default config;
```

It's also possible to do this by providing a folder when running `playwright` from the command line:

```bash
npx playwright test path/to/tests/playwright
```

Comment: Note, this won't stop tests from running outside this directory.

Comment: @FiddleFreak Let's say I have some tests in `./test` and `./.example`, I set `testDir` to `./tests`, and run `playwright test`. Are you saying the tests in `./example` would run as well? If not, could you clarify?