# Playwright ONLY run tests from a specified folder and ignore all other tests

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Given the following directory structure...

```
- /src/__mocks__
  - X.spec.tsx <-- mock test
  - Y.spec.tsx <-- mock test
  - Z.spec.tsx <-- mock test
- /src/e2e_tests <-------------- only run the tests inside this directory
  - X.spec.tsx <-- end-to-end test
  - Y.spec.tsx <-- end-to-end test
  - Z.spec.tsx <-- end-to-end test
- /src/components
  - A.tsx
  - A.spec.tsx <-- unit test
  - B.tsx
  - B.spec.tsx <-- unit test
  - C.tsx
  - C.spec.tsx <-- unit test
- /src/views
  - X.tsx
  - X.spec.tsx <-- unit test
  - Y.tsx
  - Y.spec.tsx <-- unit test
  - Z.tsx
  - Z.spec.tsx <-- unit test
- /src
  - App.tsx
  - index.tsx
- jest.config.ts
- playwright.config.ts
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- tsconfig.spec.json
- ect...
```

I've tried the following: [How do you specify a test folder/path with Playwright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72750221/how-do-you-specify-a-test-folder-path-with-playwright), however, this will also attempt to run all the tests outside the folder.

I've tried reading through the docs here: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration and have tried the following combination:

- testDir
- testIgnore
- testMatch

but can't get only `e2e_tests` directory tests to run while ignoring all other tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a project in your existing playwright config file and just add the `testDir` there, something like:

```js
projects: [
  {
    name: 'chromium',
    use: {...devices['Desktop Chrome']},
  },
  {
    name: 'firefox',
    use: {...devices['Desktop Firefox']},
  },
  {
    name: 'webkit',
    use: {...devices['Desktop Safari']},
  },
  {
    name: 'e2e_tests',
    testDir: './src/e2e_tests',
    testMatch: /.*.spec.tsx/,
  },
]
```

And then run your tests like:

```js
npx playwright test --project=e2e_tests
```

Comment: I've tried both ways and it says no tests found. I'm going to see if I can build up an app tonight to have code to test with and edit this question with it if it's not working/answered by then.

Comment: what is your existing `testDir`?

Comment: `testDir: './src/e2e_tests'`

Comment: I mean what was the value of testDir when all the tests were getting executed or better add the folder structure of your tests from the root.

Comment: I cannot access the screenshot because of permission. Would be good if you add it directly to the question.

Comment: Screenshot can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k2va9e8fvWM_8hXz_V_bd03RG8rsEtp8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This doesn't help at all as it doesn't show the folder structure. So I will try to rephrase the question - From the project root, is your e2e tests under `tests/src/e2e_tests` ?

Comment: just `src/e2e_tests`. So it's `project_name/src/e2e_tests/...` and the config is sitting inside the `project_name/`. This would probably be a lot easier if I can spin up a repo on codesandbox or github and add it to the question. I'll try to do that tonight. I have things I have to get done.

Comment: This should work as I tried it locally. I also added `testMatch: /.*.spec.tsx/,` as well, may be you can try with this once.

Comment: And I am not sure in your cli command why you are writing `playwright test npx`, it should be `npx playwright test`. The level from where you are running the tests from there you have to write the path of the test folder, that is why a screenshot of the folder structure would have solved the issue quicker.

Comment: Silly me, I copy pasted `cross-env BABEL_ENV=test playwright test npx --project=e2e_tests` instead of `cross-env BABEL_ENV=test playwright test --project=e2e_tests` in the package.json. Yeah the first and 2nd option works. Thanks. Also, just adding testDir seems to also have worked if you leave everything else default.

Answer (score 2):

Just using the playwright command line should do the job

Setup your configuration to look for all `*.spec.tsx` files for test and run

```
npx playwright test src/e2e_tests
```

Documentation ref: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-cli

Comment: i think the correct usage would be `npx playwright test -c src/e2e_tests/` original command without `test` does not work